# What would happen if I define 4 as the imaginary unit?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

In complex analysis, $\sqrt{-1} = i$ holds by definition. But why did people choose for this, instead of some other unit? What would happen if we define it to be a real number such as $\sqrt{-1} := 4 \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: You then get $-1=16$...

Comment: Its square will(**can**) not be -1 (ie negative)

Comment: We never thought about $-1 = 16$. Thank you.

Comment: And if if’s and an’s were pots and pans,
The tinker would never work!

Comment: Not to be a jerk about this, but 4 is not a unit. Still, it would be very educational to try something like $\sqrt{-1} = -i$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition of $\sqrt{-1}$ is a number such that $(\sqrt{-1})^2=-1$. Thus, if $\sqrt{-1}=a\in\Bbb R$ then $-1=a^2$, by definition. So $a^2\geq 0$ but also $a^2=-1<0$, a contradiction.

This proves that to define $\sqrt{-1}$ we have to go outside the real numbers.